# Xcode as an alternative of flash

Tags: php, xcode, flash

We have developed a magazine reader which is basically PHP application. Admin panel is built in PHP but when any user wants to read a particular magazine, it is handled by Flash i.e. we are embedding the .swf object with HTML in PHP page. But flash is not supported in iPad/iPhone. So we want to create this application in Xcode so that user can read the magazine in iPhone/iPad also. There is confusion how it can be accomplished. Does anyone has created any application similar to this??

Regards,

Vrunda Variya

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.  Your question will likely be closed soon, because it is not a good fit for SO's question and answer format.  See the FAQ and rephrase it to get more and better results.  Also, check out haXe:http://haxe.org/doc/intro

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a Web app, you will have to go the HTML5, CSS, Javascript route, if you want to have your site but rather force iOS user's to view the content on a native app, just make sure you link them to your app, here is a tut on how to use [Custom URL Schemes](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html), here is a link to the [Newsstand API Overview](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/newsstand/) ( you need an Apple dev account ) a very solid way to distribute magazine like subscriptions on apps, and you get featured as a Newsstand app (read so you can understand it more it might not be what you need), I think you need to have a clear idea of what you are trying to accomplish so that you can decide on what are the best tools for the job.

Hope this helps!

Comment: We have created a simple application in Xcode in which we are displaying the pdf pages, user can Zoom-in, Zoom-out on the pages. We don't want to create the entire application i.e. we want to have the admin panel as it is(i.e. in php). And instead of flash(as flash is not supported in iPad/iPhone), we want to apply the facilities like zooming, hotspot in Xcode. How can I integrate the code(developed in Xcode) with php??

Comment: I guess then the answer is, you can't natively, you will have to re do everything you just did with "Xcode" which I'm assuming is Objective-C using the iOS framework. Question: why aren't you just displaying the PDF's on your site with links, and let the internal PDF client form webkit do the rest? It already has pinch and zoom